# Powershell - Create GPO firewall rule for WMI

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to create below GPO Firewall rules via Powershell

[image]

Here are properties of existing rules (i want to create with powershell)

```
Get-NetFirewallRule | where {$_.Name -like "WMI*"}


Name                  : WMI-RPCSS-In-TCP
DisplayName           : Windows Management Instrumentation (DCOM-In)
Description           : Inbound rule to allow DCOM traffic for remote Windows Management Instrumentation. [TCP 135]
DisplayGroup          : Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)
Group                 : @FirewallAPI.dll,-34251
Enabled               : True
Profile               : Domain, Private, Public
Platform              : {}
Direction             : Inbound
Action                : Allow
EdgeTraversalPolicy   : Block
LooseSourceMapping    : False
LocalOnlyMapping      : False
Owner                 : 
PrimaryStatus         : OK
Status                : The rule was parsed successfully from the store. (65536)
EnforcementStatus     : NotApplicable
PolicyStoreSource     : PersistentStore
PolicyStoreSourceType : Local

    
Name                  : WMI-ASYNC-In-TCP
DisplayName           : Windows Management Instrumentation (ASync-In)
Description           : Inbound rule to allow Asynchronous WMI traffic for remote Windows Management Instrumentation. [TCP]
DisplayGroup          : Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)
Group                 : @FirewallAPI.dll,-34251
Enabled               : True
Profile               : Domain, Private, Public
Platform              : {}
Direction             : Inbound
Action                : Allow
EdgeTraversalPolicy   : Block
LooseSourceMapping    : False
LocalOnlyMapping      : False
Owner                 : 
PrimaryStatus         : OK
Status                : The rule was parsed successfully from the store. (65536)
EnforcementStatus     : NotApplicable
PolicyStoreSource     : PersistentStore
PolicyStoreSourceType : Local
```

Here is my code for creating one of those rules

```
$GpoName = "Global-WinRM"
$PolicyStoreName = "abc.com\" + $GpoName
$GpoSessionName = Open-NetGPO –PolicyStore $PolicyStoreName
New-NetFirewallRule -Name "Windows Management I" -DisplayName "Windows Management Instrumentation (ASync-In)" -DisplayGroup  "Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)" -Group "%systemroot%\system32\wbem\unsecapp.exe" -Profile Domain -Action Allow -GPOSession $GpoSessionName -Verbose
```

Error:

New-NetFirewallRule : The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:1

- New-NetFirewallRule -Name "Windows Management I" -DisplayName "Window ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (MSFT_NetFirewallRule:root/standardcimv2/MSFT_NetFirewallRule) [New-NetFirewallRule], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error 2,New-NetFirewallRule
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forgot to add `-Program` argument

```
$GpoName = "Global-WinRM"
$PolicyStoreName = "abc.com\" + $GpoName
$GpoSessionName = Open-NetGPO –PolicyStore $PolicyStoreName
New-NetFirewallRule -Name "Windows Management I" -DisplayName "Windows Management Instrumentation (ASync-In)" -Group "@FirewallAPI.dll,-34251" -Program "%systemroot%\system32\wbem\unsecapp.exe" -Profile Domain -Action Allow -GPOSession $GpoSessionName -Verbose
Save-NetGPO -GPOSession $GpoSessionName
```